# adding custom image to jquery button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add my image to a button using JQUERY,
I tried the same from example   https://forum.jquery.com/topic/custom-icons-on-jquery-ui-button,
but its not working for me. Link for my plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/PjsMCzsR0fAG2sGo6utK?p=preview

Updated url for image file.
here is my code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style> 
.ui-wp-icon {
    background-image: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/1714/dropline_neu/128/edit_undo.png) !important;
}
</style>   

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $( "#wpbutton" ).button({
        icons: { primary: "ui-wp-icon"}
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="wpbutton">Wordpress</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://findicons.com/icon/185393/edit_undo?id=398917 doesn't link to an image.

Comment: updated the background-image url, also plunker

Comment: try the new library <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @HarshKaushal  created jsfiddle  with jquery UI 1.10.2, http://jsfiddle.net/9zayLqn5/ ,not working.

Comment: I see that you've already asked 30 questions but never marked any answer as "accepted". I'm not just saying this for my own answer, but it would be nice if you would actually click the checkmark next to an answer to accept it, if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `.ui-icon` class on your button sets the background position to `16px 16px`. Remove that class, or overwrite it in your CSS using:

```
background-position: 0 0;
```

Also, your image is a lot bigger than the space it should fit in. You will only see the top left bit, which is transparent. Set the background size to fit inside the icon element:

```
background-size: contain;
```

So your CSS now becomes:

```
.returnIcon {
    background-image: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/1714/dropline_neu/128/edit_undo.png) !important;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: contain
}
```